# Can someone help me understand Solr search behaviour in this case?

Tags: search, solr, schema

Query is this :- (Profisee)
Indexed Field has the exact same token as in the above input query. But Solr search is giving zero results.
If Query is this :- (Profisee
Then I am able to find the document in the result.

P.S: I am able to get the document result for (Pro, (Profi, (Profise etc queries also.
Here are the attached images.

[Exact Query No Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwHBS.jpg)

[Inexact Query Got Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eYeQ.jpg)

[Here is my schema.xml definition for the fieldtype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMa4a.jpg)

Comment: Could you include the output of the `debug.parsedQuery` value in your question? I would also be curious to see what parsed your are using `debug.QParser`

Comment: Please don't publish code as image. How do you expect us to correct it or make annotations to it? Please include code in code boxes in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, please include the relevant details in your question next time, as images are hard to search, makes it hard to get the overview of your question and is hard to read for those that doesn't have perfect vision.

For your actual question, the problem is that you have a WhitespaceTokenizer. This will *only* break words on whitespace, such as . The indexed document contains your term as `(foo)`, which means that only `(foo)` will match (since the tokenizer *only* breaks on whitespace, and `(` or `)` isn't whitespace).

`foo (bar)` will be indexed as two tokens, `foo` and `(bar)`. Searching for `(bar` will match neither.

Use the StandardTokenizer to get the behaviour you want, or use a WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory to break the word into further tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will try to post a clean question next time. As for the current issue, I get that `foo (bar)` will be indexed as `foo` and `(bar)`, in my case, `(bar` (or `(b` or `(ba`) is giving the desired document in the search whereas `(bar)` isn't giving the required result. I need to capture the token as `(bar)` itself so that's why the WhitespaceTokenizer.

Comment: That's caused by the `EdgeNgramFilter` and the stemming filter you have attached. If you don't want that behavior, remove them (I missed that part of your question because of the text being in the images and not knowing what I should look for)

Comment: I need to have `EdgeNgramFilter` so that either `(b` or `(ba` or `(bar` or `(bar)` could match with the input query and I also need to account for special characters like `@`,`!`,`_` etc, that's why I need the `WhiteSpaceTokenizer`. Having said that, I am still seeing no result for this particular case when the entered query is `(bar)` but getting 0 results. Please help!

Comment: Are you escaping your `(`-s properly? Remember that `(` and `)` have special meaning in Lucene query syntax (i.e. field1:(val1 AND val2), where `(` and `)` isn't considered part of the query. You can escape these characters by prepending them with \.

Comment: Thanks for the response @MatsLindh. So, based on your answer, I have implemented this tokenizer `<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[^ \t\r\n]+" group="0"/>` instead of the `WhiteSpaceTokenizer` but I am still getting the same reponse. Could you guide me through the implemention of a tokenizer so that parenthesis are escaped properly? (also note that my solr version is 5.2.1)

Comment: Escaping isn't a tokenizer issue. It's the responsibility of the client making the request. It either happens automagically for you if you're using a Solr client, or if you're making manual queries, you have to do the escaping yourself.

Comment: For some query like `(bar)` I need to match it with the same token `(bar)` that gets generated in the index. You said that this particular case is different because of the usage of parenthesis. So I need to know how to escape these parenthesis in the index so that I can obtain an exact match for `(bar)`. Can you help me?

Comment: `\(bar\)` when querying should make sure that the actual text `(bar)` is passed on to the analysis chain, with the default query parser. The problem is that if you're _not_ escaping the parenthesis, the analyzer chain will never see them. That's what's happening when you have both and opening and an ending parenthesis.

Comment: Yes just tried with backslash and its working. But is there a way to let user enter parenthesis as is and make Solr escape those brackets and get a match?.

Comment: That would be the job of your controller, since Solr can't automagically determine whether you want the parenthesis to be part of the query syntax or not. You could try the `edismax` query parser instead (`defType=edismax`), but I'd think that would have support for parenthesis in the query syntax as well.